# Watch option is not triggered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, composable

i am using `vuejs3` with `options api`. as shown in the code posted below, i create a compsable class `ClsUseStates.js`, in which the value of `state` changes every second.
in `app.vue`, i instantiated an object of `ClsUseStates` and when the button in `app.vue` is clicked i call the method `useStates` to start generating the different states every second.

i wanted to reflect the changes or the different states occur in `ClsUseStates` in `app.vue`. to achieve that, in `app.vue` i created the variable `state` of type `ref`

the `<span> state: {{ state }}</span>` displays the changed states as suppose to be, when i run the code, and click the button, the text changes as follows:

```
started
processing
successful
```

but the problem i am facing is, the `watch:{ state(oldval, newval) { console.log(oldval); console.log(newval); } }` does not trigger the changes

please let me know why the changes in the value of `state` is not reflected in `watch`

i expect, that whin i click the button, to see the `console.log` shows the different values of `state` as well

**ClsUseStates.js**

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default class ClsUseStates {
    state = ref('not-satrted');
    constructor() {}

    useStates() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState('started')
        }, 1000);
      
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState('processing')
        }, 2000);
      
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState('successful')
        }, 3000);
    }

    setState(state) {
        this.state.value = state;
    }
    getState() {
        return this.state;
    }
}
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
    <button @click="onDigitizePolygon()">
        click
    </button>
    <span> state: {{ state }}</span>
</template>

<script>
import {ref} from 'vue'
import ClsUseStates from './composables/ClsUseStates.js'

let cls = new ClsUseStates()
let state = ref('---')

export default {
  data() {
        return {
            state
        };
    },
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  },
  methods: {
    onDigitizePolygon() {
      cls.useStates()
      state.value = cls.getState()
    }
  },
  watch:{
    state(oldval, newval) {
      console.log(oldval);
      console.log(newval);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you seem to be mixing *options API* and *composition API* syntax in `App.vue` - so, does `state` refer to `let state = ref('---')` or `data() { return { state };},`

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry, but i though that `let state = ref.....` will be relevant to `data() {return { state}...`

Comment: options and composition API's in the one `.vue` file is not valid

Comment: @JaromandaX would you please point out where in my code i am using options api and where i am using composition api please..and how to fix it?

Comment: I did so in my first comment - fix it by NOT using both methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found the answer. the `watch` option should have been looked like as follows. `state.value` must have been watched not `state`

```
watch:{
   'state.value'(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(oldVal);
    console.log(newVal);
   },
}
```